# Mysql - how to view bigger tables to see information from cmd?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a form which submits data to a table in a database, but it is difficult to view this information in the cmd window.

Where or how can view it the table better?

Answer (score 0):

I use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to administer my MySQL databases for both *nix & Windows.

Also you could use [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/demo.html) for *nix

Answer (score 0):

The official GUI tools for mySQL can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).